# Hosting advice for a write-heavy dynamic website

Tags: web-hosting, php, mysql, optimization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I have built a website using PHP and MySQL and now I am looking for a hosting service. I am expecting about a 1000 users registering and about 5-10k pageviews/day in a week's time. So which host should I opt for?

It will let users submit contents of type blobs and submit around 10 pictures per users. I hope that traffic will increase so can justhost's or bluehost's shared hosting serve that purpose or should I go for more dedicated ones. Basically the site is write heavy and there are average 2-3 MySQL queries per page and it is quite dynamic. So depending on these requirements which web hosting will be optimal for me.

Comment: duplicate of what??